Android/Java:ArrayIndeexOutOfBounds error was reported while setting text with a non-null SpannableStringBuuilder parameter
How I encountered this error
I generated a SpannableStringBuilder object by a series of options firstly,then I stored the object and read it in another method,trying to set textview's text with that,however an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error was reported at that time.
My conjecture
I think the most possible reason is that the object isn't serialized correctly while storing,but I don't know how to solve it.
Difficulties
I can't understand the error log fully,because I can't find where the array,which's size is 0,is.
Desired result
The content of the object should be shown onto the screen
Error details
Error log

2024-08-20 20:22:38.811 23328-23328 AndroidRuntime          pers.beapoe.fortest                  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: pers.beapoe.fortest, PID: 23328
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:473)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7188)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1213)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7165)
at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:814)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27657)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:230)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7887)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:526)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:468)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7188) 
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1213) 
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7165) 
at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:814) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27657) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:230) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7887) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:526) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034) 
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.getSpansRec(SpannableStringBuilder.java:976)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.getSpans(SpannableStringBuilder.java:880)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.getSpans(SpannableStringBuilder.java:849)
at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.copySpans(SpannableStringInternal.java:69)
at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.<init>(SpannableStringInternal.java:45)
at android.text.SpannedString.<init>(SpannedString.java:35)
at android.text.SpannedString.<init>(SpannedString.java:44)
at android.text.TextUtils.stringOrSpannedString(TextUtils.java:531)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6272)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6174)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6126)
at pers.beapoe.fortest.main.onClick(main.java:169)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:468) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7188) 
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1213) 
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7165) 
at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:814) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27657) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:230) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7887) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:526) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)

Step to reproduce

Create an Android application
Add dependency "gson" into this app
Replace the activity and xml file's code with the code in next title(Code to reproduce)
Tip:Please make sure that two files are named "main.java" and "main.xml"
Build and run the app
Tap the button "Next chapter",then you'll see the error in the logcat

Code to reproduce
Java code(main.java)
public class main extends AppCompatActivity {
    SpannableStringBuilder content = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    public final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(SpannableStringBuilderAdapter.class,new SpannableStringBuilderAdapter())
            .create();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final String TAG = "ForTest:OnCreate(...)";

        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        lines.add("    hello world");
        lines.add("    •<this is what to replace>•");
        lines.add("    •&be used to replace&•");

        ArrayList<String> Replacements = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Span> spans = new ArrayList<>();
        // 将String转换为char的ArrayList，方便索引补全
        ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();
        for (char ch : String.join("\n", lines).toCharArray()) chars.add(ch);

        // 循环判断是否是特殊字符
        int SpanTimes = -1;
        try {
            for (int outside = 0; outside < chars.size() - 1; outside++) {
                Span span = new Span();

                // 如果遇到了初始开始符
                if (chars.get(outside) == '•' && chars.get(outside + 1) == '<') {
                    // 将此时的迭代标识设为Span的开始索引
                    span.setStart(outside - 1);
                    boolean FoundEnd = false;

                    // 嵌套循环从特殊字符之后的字符开始寻找初始结束符
                    inner:
                    for (int inside = outside + 2; inside < chars.size() - 1; inside++) {
                        if (chars.get(inside) == '>' && chars.get(inside + 1) == '•') {
                            FoundEnd = true;
                            // 将此时的嵌套迭代标识的下一位，即‘•’设为Span的结束索引
                            span.setEnd(inside - 2);
                            // 将该Span添加到Spans里，并使Span计数加一
                            spans.add(span);
                            SpanTimes += 1;
                            // 删除初始开始符
                            for (int remove = 0; remove < 2; remove++)
                                chars.remove(span.getStart() + 1);
                            // 删除初始结束符
                            for (int remove = 0; remove < 2; remove++) chars.remove(span.getEnd());
                            //将初始结束符的索引设为外部迭代标识符
                            outside = span.getEnd();
                            break inner;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!FoundEnd) {
                        // 如果没找到初始结束符，自杀
                        Log.e(TAG, "No end(>•) found");
                        android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
                        System.exit(1);
                    }

                } else if (chars.get(outside) == '•' && chars.get(outside + 1) == '&') {
                    // 如果找到了替换开始符
                    boolean FoundEnd = false;
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    // 嵌套循环寻找替换结束符
                    inner:
                    for (int inside = outside + 2; inside < chars.size()-1; inside++) {
                        if (chars.get(inside) == '&' && chars.get(inside + 1) == '•') {
                            FoundEnd = true;
                            // 删除文本之中要替换的字符
                            if(inside+2==chars.size()){
                                chars.subList(outside,inside).clear();
                                for(int counter=0;counter<2;counter++) chars.remove(outside);
                                outside -= 1;
                            }else{
                                chars.subList(outside, inside + 2).clear();
                            }
                            break inner;
                        }
                        // 将替换开始符之后的字符作为Replacement的值
                        sb.append(chars.get(inside));
                    }
                    // 删除多余空格
                    if (chars.get(outside) == '\n') chars.subList(outside - 5, outside).clear();
                    if(chars.get(outside)==' '){
                        chars.subList(outside-3,outside).clear();
                        chars.remove(outside-3);
                        outside = outside-4;
                    }
                    if (!FoundEnd) {
                        // 如果没找到替换结束符，自杀
                        Log.e(TAG, "No end(&•) found");
                        android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                    Replacements.add(sb.toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            // 如果出现数组越界，自杀
            Log.e(TAG, "Error processing the special content", new IndexOutOfBoundsException("处理特别章节的文本时出错"));
            android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        // 设置替换内容
        for (int index = 0; index < spans.size(); index++)
            spans.get(index).setReplacement(Replacements.get(index));
        // 合成Spannable内容
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(char ch:chars) sb.append(ch);
        content.append(sb.toString());
        // 为每个Span设置color并添加到Spannable
        for (Span span : spans) content.setSpan(span.getColor(), span.getStart(), span.getEnd(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        test test = new test(content);
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("sp",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putString("c",gson.toJson(test));
        editor.apply();
        test ss = gson.fromJson(sp.getString("c",""),new TypeToken<test>(){}.getType());
        SpannableStringBuilder c = ss.getSsb();
        int i = 2;
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        TextView Read = findViewById(R.id.Read);
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("sp",MODE_PRIVATE);
        test ssb = gson.fromJson(sp.getString("c",""),new TypeToken<test>(){}.getType());
        Read.setText(ssb.getSsb());
    }

    public static class test implements Serializable {
        private SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        public test(SpannableStringBuilder ssb){this.ssb = ssb;}

        public SpannableStringBuilder getSsb() {
            return ssb;
        }
    }

    static class Span{
        private int start = 0;
        private int end = 0;
        private String Replacement = "";
        private ForegroundColorSpan color = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE);

        public Span(){}

        public int getStart() {
            return start;
        }

        public void setStart(int start) {
            this.start = start;
        }

        public int getEnd() {
            return end;
        }

        public void setEnd(int end) {
            this.end = end;
        }

        public void setReplacement(String replacement) {
            Replacement = replacement;
        }

        public ForegroundColorSpan getColor() {
            return color;
        }
    }

    static class SpannableStringBuilderAdapter implements JsonSerializer<SpannableStringBuilder>, JsonDeserializer<SpannableStringBuilder> {
        @Override
        public SpannableStringBuilder deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            return new SpannableStringBuilder(Html.fromHtml(json.getAsString(),Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY).toString());
        }

        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(SpannableStringBuilder src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
            return new JsonPrimitive(Html.toHtml(src,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
        }
    }
}

XML code(main.xml)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ReadParent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Read"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/Read"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Next"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:backgroundTint="#A9AAAD"
                    android:onClick="onClick"
                    android:text="Next chapter"
                    android:textColor="#263238"
                    tools:ignore="VisualLintButtonSize" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>

Thanks for help!

Direct reason
The custom adapter wasn't registered correctly
Detail
The first parameter passed to method:registerTypeAdapter() should be the type that will call the custom adapter while it's being serializeing,instead of tht custom adapter
How to solve
change the code in the fourth line:
.registerTypeAdapter(SpannableStringBuilderAdapter.class,new SpannableStringBuilderAdapter())

into:
.registerTypeAdapter(SpannableStringBuilder.class,new SpannableStringBuilderAdapter())

